# SSH how to auto flush before a \n

Tags: ssh

I am using this kind of commands :

```
ssh -i etc/ssh/vagrant vagrant@34.34.34.10 "cd floss_project; make install"
```

But if during the installation script, a user prompt is needed, I cannot see what is the question asked since, the CLI is not flush into the SSH before a `\n`.

How can I ask SSH to auto flush the prompt before the `\n` so I can see which answer I should give?

**Edit:**

To Help you to reproduce this bug, let say we have the following script:

**name.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
name = raw_input('Give me your name: ')
print("Hello "+name)
```

We decide to launch it with ssh:

```
$ ssh 127.0.0.1 python name.py
```

The curser is waiting for our input without actually asking for the wanted `Give me your name:`

How can I force SSH to display this information (actually to flush the STDOUT before a STDIN)

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not in the missing tty? I could not reproduce this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.security.ssh/2005-03/0056.html we need to use the -t option.

```
$ ssh -t 127.0.0.1 python name.py
```

Comment: Complementing this answer with an excerpt from the man page: "-t  Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty."